# How to get the paragraph number from a word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to achieve the following requirement but I am not very well versed with word documents.

What I need to get is the paragraph number and page number a specific term appears. And this data should be made a table in Excel.

I am wondering if there is a possibility to get the para# from a word document from Excel VBA.

Comment: Yes that is possible, but SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Break the problem into small steps, then solve each step. First, create a VBA code that will open an MS Word document and close it. Next, add a bit to search for the specific term. Then, add more code to determine the paragraph number. Keep building from there

Comment: Searching on _Word VBA get paragraph number_, _Word VBA get page number_ and _VBA automate Word from Excel_ should get you good starting points.

Answer (score 0):

Imagining you are searching for the word  "text", this is the word part.

```vb
With Selection.Find
    .Execute FindText:="text"
End With
'paragraph number
parag = Selection.Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
'page number
pg = Selection.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

In order to store this data in new excel workbook.

```vb
Set wb = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add
wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value = parag
wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1,2).Value = pg
Excel.Application.Visible = True
```

In word you would have to set a reference to Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.